# point effector without gravity in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gravity

I'm new to unity and I'm trying to create a 2D game where there planets that can pull the player in when it moves into their orbit as if they have gravity, but when it´s outside it can move freely.
I tried using a point effector for the planets but it doesn't seem to be affecting the player, I want it to be a top-down view so the player can´t keep falling due to gravity but I want it to be pulled in by the pointEffector, is there any way I can do this?

[image: inspector for the "planet"]

[image: player movement script]

[image: inspector for the player]

I tried:

- Freezing the player Y position
- Taking out the gravity of the player
- Taking out the sprite renderer from the planet object

Comment: since you directly move the object trough `transform` this will overrule physics anyway ...

Comment: And does your player have a collider2D? Otherwise it will not be detected by the effector ...

Comment: It didn't, I had forgotten to add it, but it still doesn't work, how would I go about changing the way I do the movement? maybe change the players velocity rather than the position itself?

Comment: you also would not want to overwrite the velocity as it would break the gravity effect as well ... you might rather want to use forces instead

Comment: Alternatively of course you could also just code it yourself without using Rigidbody at all. All you need is the list of planets you are currently triggered by -> iterate them and calculate movement caused by gravities from those yourself (e.g. using CharacterController)

Comment: I did think of doing that and I think I could manage it, but I wanted to try using the components within unity to do it, but I'll give it a shot with both these options. Thank you for the help!